# Python: delete all characters in a tag with exception list

Tags: python

So I would like to delete all the characters (mostly letters) from a tag but keep the words from exception list.

For example,

I would like to change

```
<html>VERY RARE CAR WITH NEW TIRES WHITE</html>
```

to:

```
<html>CAR WHITE</html>
```

that means that two words car and white are from exception list.

Comment: Sooo, what have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: `all the characters (mostly letters)`???!?

Comment: `So I would like to delete all the characters ...` -- Feel free; nobody's stopping you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for. I'll show how strip whatever text you want with 2 lists, exception words and html tags:

```
#This is to maintain the html tags unmodified
html_tags = ['<a>','</a>','<html>','</html>']  

#Exception words list
word_list = ['WORD1','CAR','WORD2','WHITE','WORD3','WORD4']  
#String you want to split
string = '<html>VERY RARE CAR WITH NEW TIRES WHITE</html>'

#The result string where we concatenate desired words and tags
final_string = ''

#now we change the string to add # before '<' and after '>' so we can split the text by tags
string = string.replace('<','#<')
string = string.replace('>','>#')

string_list = string.split('#')  #Now we have the tags unmodified (<html>,<a>...)

#Now we have:
#string_list = ['', '<html>', 'VERY RARE CAR WITH NEW TIRES WHITE', '</html>', '']

for word in string_list:  #We go over all string_list
    if (word in html_tags):  #If we find a tag, we add it to final_string
        final_string+=word
    else: #If it isn't a tag, it is text, in this case 'VERY RARE CAR WITH NEW TIRES WHITE'
        for word2 in word.split():  #We split by whitespace 
            if word2 in word_list:  #If it is in word_list, we add it to final_string
                final_string+=' '+word2+' '

#The result of this code is final_string with '<html> CAR  WHITE </html>'
#You can manage better the white spaces, and I make the code little complex 
#to make sure it works with different tags, and bigger html code.
```

Hope it helps!!